# remove index.php codeigniter 3.0.6

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, xampp

I wanted to remove the `index.php` on my URL like this. I use XAMPP.

> localhost/3g_admin/home

First I used this `.htaccess` on my version of codeigniter 3.0.0 and it works fine.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /3G_admin
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But when I use this `.htaccess` on the 3.0.6 version of CodeIgniter I need to declare this

> localhost/3g_admin/index.php/home

I already set the `config.php` to this.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Still no luck.

what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using xampp?

Comment: `RewriteBase /3G_admin/` - notice forvard slash at the end.

Comment: @Wolfgang yes I use xampp.

Comment: @Tpojka will give it a shot

Comment: Also, in third line you should escape dots `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)`.

Comment: @Tpojka Still no luck. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where I am doing wrong.

It is the declaration of the `folder` and the `rewrite base`.

**number first** names are **not** allowed. so insted of `3G_admin` I replace it into `G_admin` and it works like a charm.

naming convention and proper ruling was the problem

Answer (score 2):

In `config.php`, change

`$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

to

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

Answer (score 2):

Change in your config

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
to    
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

and also

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Some users might also require to update httpd.conf along with above changes mentioned by others

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
  </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** : Got to codeigniter folder, Open the file config.php and remove "index.php" from  `$config['index_page'] = ''`

**Step 2** : Create " `.htaccess` " file in codeigniter folder and paste below code in it

```
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Step 3** : Find  `( $config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO" )` and replace with `( $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI" )`also Check `($config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE; )`

**Step 4** :Restart xampp server and check ..